# ListView button at position not clicked proper click in android

Tags: android, listview, download, position

I displayed the list item using a custom Baseadapter class. My problem is, when I click on the listview button at the position 1, the button at position other is also clicked.but i downloaded video in back progress completelty.but listview display not properly . How do I overcome this problem?

Here is my code:

```
public class TestHopeListNew extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Url_Dto> list = new ArrayList<Url_Dto>();
    MyListAdapter adtf;
    public static String prf_date_view = "";
    String str_start;
    Button all_detail;
    Button accepted_all, mainDownloadBtn;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    String name;
    File download;
    int i = 0;
    private ArrayList<ProgressBarSeek> progreeSeekList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_hope_list_new);
        progreeSeekList = new ArrayList<ProgressBarSeek>();
        list = DBAdapter.getUrl_Detail();
        Log.v("log_tag", "list  :: " + list.size());
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_meet);
        mainDownloadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.not_shown);
        adtf = new MyListAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adtf);
        adtf.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SqliteAdpter dba = SqliteAdpter
                .getAdapterInstance(getApplicationContext());
        dba.createdatabase();
        db = dba.openDataBase();

        mainDownloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adtf.setAllDownload();
            }
        });

    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ProgressBar pr;
        ProgressBar[] prArray = new ProgressBar[list.size()];
        Button cl, dl;
        ImageView im;
        DownloadFileFromURL downloadFileFromURL;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public void setAllDownload() {
            if (prArray.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < prArray.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.v("log_tag", "list.get(i).url_video   "
                            + list.get(i).url_video);
                    downloadFileFromURL = new DownloadFileFromURL(dl, cl);
                    downloadFileFromURL.execute(pr, list.get(i).url_video, i);
                }
            }
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            public Button cl;
            public Button dl;
            public ProgressBar pr;
            public ImageView im;

        };
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            /*convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_list_view, null);
            cl = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancle_sedual);
            dl = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_sedual);
            pr = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listprogressbar);
            prArray[position] = pr;
            im = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            im.setImageResource(list.get(position).images[position]);*/

            //final ViewHolder holder = null;



            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_list_view,
                        null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                prArray[position] = pr;
                holder.cl = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.cancle_sedual);
                holder.dl = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.download_sedual);
                holder.pr = (ProgressBar) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listprogressbar);
                holder.im = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.im.setImageResource(list.get(position).images[position]);
            // pr.setProgress(getItem(position));

            holder.cl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Cancle Button Click");


                    holder.dl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.cl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //downloadFileFromURL = new DownloadFileFromURL(dl, cl);
                     downloadFileFromURL.cancel(true);
                    downloadFileFromURL.downloadFile();
                    holder.pr.setProgress(0);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            holder.dl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.dl.setFocusable(false);
                    str_start = list.get(position).url_video;
                    holder.dl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.cl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Start Button Click ");

                    // new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(str_start);
                    downloadFileFromURL = new DownloadFileFromURL(holder.dl, holder.cl);
                    downloadFileFromURL.execute(holder.pr, str_start, position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            getProgress(holder.pr, position, holder.dl, holder.cl);
        //  convertView.setTag(holder);
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Integer> {

        int count = 0;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        int myProgress;
        int position;
        Button start, cancel;
        boolean download1 = false;

        public DownloadFileFromURL(Button start, Button cancel) {
            this.start = start;
            this.cancel = cancel;
        }

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressBar progressBar;
            download1 = true;

        }

        public void downloadFile() {
            this.download1 = false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {

            int count;
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) params[0];
            position = (Integer) params[2];
            try {

                URL url = new URL((String) params[1]);

                name = ((String) params[1]).substring(((String) params[1])
                        .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                // Log.v("log_tag", "name Substring ::: " + name);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/");
                if (!download.exists()) {
                    download.mkdir();
                }
                String strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + name;
                Log.v("log_tag", " down url   " + strDownloaDuRL);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    if (this.download1) {

                        if(isCancelled()){
                            break;
                        }
                        total += count;

                        // writing data to file
                        progressBar
                                .setProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                        setProgress(progressBar, position, start, cancel, this);

                    } else {
                        File delete = new File(strDownloaDuRL);
                        delete.delete();
                    }
                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return 0;

        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            // Log.v("log_tag", "progress :: " + values);
            // setting progress percentage
            // pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            Log.v("log", "login  ::: 4::: " + download);
            String videoPath = download + "/" + name;
            String chpName = name;
            Log.v("log_tag", "chpName  ::::" + chpName + "  videoPath "
                    + videoPath);
            db.execSQL("insert into videoStatus (chapterNo,videoPath) values(\""
                    + chpName + "\",\"" + videoPath + "\" )");

        }

    }

    private void setProgress(final ProgressBar pr, final int position,
            final Button Start, final Button cancel,
            final DownloadFileFromURL downloadFileFromURL) {
        ProgressBarSeek pbarSeek = new ProgressBarSeek();
        pbarSeek.setPosition(position);
        pbarSeek.setProgressValue(pr.getProgress());
        // Log.v("log_tag", position + "  progress  " + pr.getProgress());
        progreeSeekList.add(pbarSeek);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v("log_tag", "Cancle Button Click Set progress");
                Start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downloadFileFromURL.cancel(true);
                downloadFileFromURL.downloadFile();
                pr.setProgress(0);
            }
        });
        Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Start Button Click set Progress");
                str_start = list.get(position).url_video;
                Start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.v("log_tag", "str_start  " + str_start);
                //
                // new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(str_start);
                DownloadFileFromURL downloadFileFromU = new DownloadFileFromURL(
                        Start, cancel);
                downloadFileFromU.execute(pr, str_start, position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getProgress(ProgressBar pr, int position, Button dl, Button cl) {
        if (progreeSeekList.size() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < progreeSeekList.size(); j++) {
                if (position == progreeSeekList.get(j).getPosition()) {
                    pr.setProgress(progreeSeekList.get(j).getProgressValue());
                    dl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

i click second button but display other button clickeble but second button background downloading in sd card but display not properly .how to solve it and what is wrong in my code,please helpme!!!

Comment: Do you want to download a single item at a time ?

Comment: ya i want to download a single item at time and my image in on top all download button when click then all file downloaded.